# How can I prove that $2^{n+2}\mid(2n+3)!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

I'm not sure where to proceed or how to go about proving this assertion holds for all natural numbers n:
$$2^{n+2} \mid(2n + 3)!$$

The base case is $n=1$, where $2^{1+2}\mid(2\cdot 1+3)!$ which simplifies to $8 \mid 120$, and *8* does indeed divide *120*.

Again, we shall assume the statement is true for $n = k$. 
$$2^{k+2}\mid(2k+3)!$$
Then we shall prove that the statement must be true for n = k + 1:
$$2^{k+3}\mid (2(k+1)+3)!=(2k+5)!$$

Sorry for the poor formatting, this is the first time I've posted here. I'm not sure if I've started off on the right path, or where to go next. Any suggestions would be lovely!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are $n+1$ even numbers in $1,\cdots,2n+3$ and one of them is $4$ (given $n\ge1$).

Comment: So because the divisor has 2 to the power of whatever, it will always divide whatever the quotient is due to it having a 4 in the factorial? Is this the correct way to interpret your response?

Comment: @knames You use the phrases "the divisor" and "whatever" and "it" and "the quotient" but I don't know what you're referring to with these phrases. Please be clear and specific.

Comment: the divisor being 2^(n+2) and the quotient being (2n+3)!. The left part before | will always divide the right part after | because the right part has a 4 in the factorial?

Comment: @knames The word "quotient" refers to what you get after you've divided, it doesn't refer to the thing you're dividing. Just because something is divisible by $4$ does not mean it is divisible by $2^{n+2}$; that's where the total of $n+1$ even numbers comes in. Try thinking some more about my hint.

Comment: if we have n = 1, then there are (1+1) = 2 even numbers between 1 and 2(1)+3 = 4, 2 and 4 are the even numbers. I can't seem to make the mental jump to why that's important to proving the rest of the assertion. Do you have another hint/tip to push me in the right direction. I made a list of the first few numbers you get from 1-5 with (2n+3)!, all of which can be divided by 4 with integer quotients. Is this the right step?

Comment: @knames There are $n+1$ even numbers in the range $1,\cdots,2n+3$, which each contribute a factor of $2$ into $(2n+3)!$ but $4$, one of those even numbers, also contributes an extra factor of $2$. This makes a total of $n+2$ factors of $2$ (at least) that go into $(2n+3)!$.

Comment: This is as explicit as I can make it: $$(2n+3)!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(2n+3)=(\underbrace{2\cdot\color{Red}4\cdots2n+2}_{n+1~\rm numbers})(1\cdot3\cdots2n+3)$$ $$=2^{n+1}(1\cdot\color{Red}2\cdot3\cdots n+1)(1\cdot3\cdots 2n+3)=2^{n+2}(3\cdots n+1)(1\cdot3\cdots 2n+3).$$ Honestly, I thought my hint was pretty clear and straightforward, and this level of explication was totally unnecessary.

Comment: so what I could say to finish the assertion is: 
"Each even number (there are n+1 of them) contributes a factor of 2, while 4 contributes 2 factors of 2, making a total of n+2 factors of 2 that make up (n+3!), or in other words, 2(n+2) factors of 2, proving the assertion."
Am I correct in saying that? I think I understand now if so. Also thanks for taking me through this!
------------- the above was for the post immediately after my reply, I'm just now reading your second one. Sorry, I haven't touched high level university math for years and am now in a Number Theory course for my degree...

Comment: You mean $(2n+3)!$ not $(n+3!)$, and I don't know where you are getting "$2(n+2)$ factors" from. The important thing is to understand my hint, not figure out what words to regurgitate to get points. Are you familiar with prime factorization? This should have been quick, easy and painless, and yet here we are so many comments later, and I don't understand why we've spilled so many words.

Comment: It's not letting me edit for some reason, but yes I meant [...] in other words, 2 to-the-power-of (n+2) factors of 2, proving [...].  And yes, I did mean (2n+3)!. Thanks so much, sorry I'm sure for the majority of people here your first hint was probably enough to push them in the right direction. I am not confident with my higher level math skills. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm familiar with prime factorization, it's something from gradeschool and we recapped it in class the other day. I'm not worried about the points so much as I just wanted to make sure I understood it enough to put it in my own words, but if I put it in my own words and I'm still wrong, then I'd rather know I was incorrect than think I was right and make mistakes later.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(2k+5)!=(2k+3)!(2k+4)(2k+5)$. Since by the induction hypothesis, $2^{k+2}$ divides $(2k+3)!$, and since $2$ divides $2k+4$, we conclude that $2^{k+3}$ divides $(2k+5)!$.

**Remark:** (This refers to an earlier version of the post.) In *writing up* a proof, *never* try to travel from what you want to show to something "known."

Comment: I'm new to number-theory, could you elaborate on what you meant by "In writing up a proof, never try to travel from what you want to show to something "known.""

Comment: @knames Sometimes you start from the fact that you're trying to prove and manipulate things until you've arrived at an already established fact. This is how it goes in any kind of math, number theory or no. You might even try burning both ends of the stick and meeting somewhere in the middle. At the end, though, when you actually go to write down your proof, you need to start at something known and end up at the desired claim, in that order.

Comment: In high school, people pick up the very bad habit of writing down what they want to be true, and then manipulating until they get something true, like $x=x$. This is *logically wrong*, unless one shows that every step that got us from what we want to $x=x$ is *reversible*. If one showed reversibility (which one often cannot show), it would be OK. But people who go from the desired to something known often lose control over the logic of the argument, and end up writing a confused circular non-proof. I am not saying you shouldn't fool around informally with the "desired."

Comment: But ultimately the written up argument must go "the right way" so that its validity is clear.

Comment: @blue, @ André Nicolas Thank you, this makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 2):

$(2k+5)!=(2k+5)(2k+4)(2k+3)!=(2k+5)(2k+4)2^{k+2}\cdot c$ where the last equality is due to $2^{k+2}\mid (2k+3)!$ which you assume.

Hence, $(2k+5)!=(2k+5)(k+2)(2)(2^{k+2})$. Finish it :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with $2k+2∣(2k+3)!$.  This means there exists a $b \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(2k+3)! =  b2^{k+2}$.

$$\begin{align*}
(2k+3)! =  b2^{k+2} & \Rightarrow  (2k+3)!(2k+4)(2k+5) = b2^{k+2}(2k+4)(2k+5)&
\\ & \Leftrightarrow (2k+5)!  = b2^{k+2}2(k+2)(2k+5)
\\ & \Leftrightarrow (2k+5)! = (b(k+2)(2k+5))2^{k+3}
\\ & \Rightarrow 2^{k+3} | (2k+5)!
\\ & \Leftrightarrow 2^{(k+1)+2} | (2(k+1)+3)!
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Just a quick question, what is the significance of including the last line? Why break down the exponent and everything to the right of the "|"?

Comment: It makes the induction pedantically clear.  This expression is a straight substitution of $(k+1)$ for $k$ in the equation we're trying to prove.

Answer (score 0):

### Theory

The number of factors of the prime number, p, that divide into n! is
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i} \right \rfloor$

As formidable as this equation may look, it's not really that bad.

First of all, once $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i} \right \rfloor$ becomes $0$, all of the terms after that are also $0$. So it's really a finite sum.

Second, it can be shown that
$$
\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^{i+1}} \right \rfloor =
\left \lfloor
   \dfrac{\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i} \right \rfloor}{p}
 \right \rfloor
$$

So, knowing the value of $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i} \right \rfloor$ makes it easier to compute $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^{i+1}} \right \rfloor$.

### Application

We make the following computations.

- $\left \lfloor \dfrac{2n+3}{2} \right \rfloor = n+1$

  $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor \ge 1
       \quad (\forall n \ge 1)$

It follows that the highest power of 2 that divides into $(2n+3)!$ is greater than or equal to $(n+1) + 1 = n+2$. In other words, $2^{n+2} | (2n+3)!$